# Increment svg text with commas

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to increment some text from one number to another in d3.js. [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/c5YVX/) does exactly what I am looking for, but I need to pass in a number that has a dollar sign and commas, not just a number. If I try to pass in a value that I've formatted, it returns NaN. Any advice?

Example:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
        var parts = x.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return parts.join(".");
    }
var foo = numberWithCommas(2000); //foo now = 2,000

d3.select('body')
  .text(0)
  .transition()
  .duration(duration)
  .ease('linear')
  .tween("text", function() {
    var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, foo);
    return function(t) {
    this.textContent = Math.round(i(t));
  };
});
```

**EDIT**: My solution:

```
d3.select("#totaltext")
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .ease('linear')
            .tween("text", function() {
                var i = d3.interpolate(this.textContent, sum);
                return function(t) {
                  this.textContent = '$' + d3.format(",")(Math.round(i(t)));
                };
              })
```

Comment: Could you use a format to format the actual number? E.g. http://jsfiddle.net/c5YVX/26/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to strip the $ and the comma sign, something like this...

```
var number = Number(x.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
```

If you want to interpolate the currency you'd have to [create a custom interpolator](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Transitions#wiki-d3_interpolate)

```
d3.interpolators.push(function(a, b) {
  var re = /^\$([0-9,.]+)$/, ma, mb, f = d3.format(",.02f");
  if ((ma = re.exec(a)) && (mb = re.exec(b))) {
    a = parseFloat(ma[1]);
    b = parseFloat(mb[1]) - a;
    return function(t) {
      return "$" + f(a + b * t);
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I want the number that is changing to have a $ and commas. So the user sees $2,000